# Delete rectangle on TBitmap in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

```
  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.SetSize(Screen.Width,Screen.Height);

  bmp.canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear; 
  bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := clLime;
  bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(startPos.X,startPos.Y,stopPos.X,stopPos.Y); <-draw rectangle
```

Is there a simple way to delete the Old rectangle without refreshing the entire image?

I want to select a region of this image, like they do in grafic programs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Delphi XE** with **FireMonkey**, you don't need to care about it, just use a **TSelection** component that allows you to show a region, modify and get information from the region...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete things from a raster image. Each pixel must have a value. All you can do is draw something else over what is already there.

So if you want to restore what was there before, you must remember what it was, and draw it again.

Drawing programs maintain layers, and merge those layers into a single image for rendering. You could do that too, but you have to do it yourself with multiple bitmaps, one per layer.

If you want to draw a selection rectangle you don't need to draw on the underlying bitmap. When you need to paint you paint the bitmap to the screen and then paint the rectangle on top. That way you don't let the selection rectangle spoil the actual image.

Comment: Yeah, this is the modern way of doing it. But of course one could also  use some injective transformation, e.g. an involution.

Comment: I agree it's better to do it the way you describe. But many years ago, that might have been a bit to heavy.

Comment: You mean xor pen or the like?

Comment: Yes, or you could invert the colour, or darken or lighten or whatever, as long as you can restore it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to draw a *selection rectangle* which is typically bound by mouse movement, thus *deleting* the previously drawn rectangle and drawing a new one at the current mouse position. This can be done by drawing with the pen in XOR mode:

```
function NegativeColor(AColor: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := RGB(255 - GetRValue(AColor), 255 - GetGValue(AColor),
    255 - GetBValue(AColor));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button14Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bmp.SetSize(100, 100);
    Bmp.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Color := NegativeColor(clLime);
    Bmp.Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmXor;
    Bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50);
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Bmp);
    Bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 50); // "Erase" previous rectangle
    Bmp.Canvas.Rectangle(10, 10, 90, 90); // Draw new rectangle
    Canvas.Draw(0, 100, Bmp);
  finally
    Bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This fails when the color channels have value $80. I see no need to use a destructive method likes this. It also can lead to a very odd looking rectangle with strange colors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply way is work with `TShape` to select, and when done selected hide it and draw shape by
coordinate of this TShape .